# How to convert to Mesh from Curve with Python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bezier-curves

I'm making a bunch of abstract objects that are shaped programmatically. I use a Bezier curve, you get nice molds with few points. Then I need to convert it into a mesh object. Blender version is 2.80.

It's easy to get a mesh object from a curve manually:

[image: A curve is about to be converted to a mesh.]

Keep the original curve object so it can be reused:

[image: A new mesh object has been created.]

In edit mode the vertices are there so it really is a mesh object:

[image: The new mesh object in edit mode. A lot of points on a curve-looking wiggly path.]

Now how you do the same with a Python script? I've tried this that and the other but only got various error messages. I'm sure there must be a simple way to do that. Let's not go through all my trials but I attach some error messages just to show you I've been working on this:

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.convert.poll() failed, context is incorrect
>
> RuntimeError: Error: Can not create object in main database with an evaluated data data-block
>
> ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Mesh has been removed

Comment: Turned out that I don't need to do that because I found Screw Modifier that does everything (that I didn't even describe here), and this step became a misstep. The problem has vanished.